# Send data over GSM radio

Tags: android, gsm, android-networking

I just got a nexus S android device.

I was wondering if I can send data over its GSM radio? if possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [rapidsms](http://www.rapidsms.org/) and [pygsm](https://github.com/adammck/pygsm/wiki)

Pygsm will let you send data over GSM radio as a SMS message. Rapidsms is a higher-level open-source framework for dynamic data collection using SMS.